# Add events to tag in Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

So I decidedd to use Datatables and I managed to make datatables load data from json but I do not know how to add onclick event or class to rows.

Here is the old code I used:

```
    <tbody id="skladove_table">

 <?php
  $query_checkObekt = "SELECT * FROM obekti WHERE owner='$user_hash'";
  $result_checkObekt = mysqli_query($conn, $query_checkObekt);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result_checkObekt) > 0) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE owner ='$user_hash'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

            {
              echo '<tr id="' . $row['unique_id'] . '" onmouseover=showItem(' . $row['unique_id'] . ');>';

              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['custom_id'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['name'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['barcode'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['grupa'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['quantity_type'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['quantity_number'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['obekt'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['price_delivery'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['price_sale'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td style='width: 1%; padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%;' onclick='deleteItem(" . $row['unique_id'] . ");'><i class='fa fa-close'></i>"."</td>";

              echo "</tr>";
            }

  } else {
    //if no records in DB
  }

  ?>

  </tbody>
```

If I use this code I can't refresh the Datatable. Since I started using ajax to populate the table I just can't make it look the same. I do not know how to add the onclick events (which have custom parameter for every row).

This is the code I use now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {  
  $('#products_all').DataTable({ 
        "language": {"url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Bulgarian.json"},
        "colReorder" : true,
        "resetPaging" : false,
        "columnDefs" : [{"orderable": false, "targets": 9 }], 
       "ajax" : "generate_json/get_items.php",  
       "columns" : [  
            {"data" : "custom_id"},  
            {"data" : "name"},
            {"data" : "barcode"}, 
            {"data" : "grupa"},
            {"data" : "quantity_type"},
            {"data" : "quantity_number"},
            {"data" : "obekt"},
            {"data" : "price_delivery"},
            {"data" : "price_sale"},
            {"data" : "delete"},
            //{"data" : null, "defaultContent" : "<i style='padding: 5px;' class='fa fa-close'></i>"},

       ]  
  });
```

});

Comment: You can use rowcallback: https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback

Comment: @alanfcm how can I insert something into this from the array which I retreived using ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowCallback`, in there you can add anything you want to the row, like a click handler, a class or more content.  Something like this:

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
  $(row).addClass('myClass');
  $(row).click(function() {
    alert('hello');
  });    
}
```